Postgresql - How to calculate swipe in and swipe out time
This is my data.



username
building
action
timestamp




user-1
building-1
IN
2024-04-10 01:00:00.000


user-1
building-1
OUT
2024-04-10 02:00:00.000


user-1
building-1
IN
2024-04-10 02:30:00.000


user-1
building-1
OUT
2024-04-10 04:00:00.000


user-1
building-1
IN
2024-04-11 10:00:00.000


user-1
building-1
OUT
2024-04-11 11:00:00.000


user-2
building-2
IN
2024-04-10 08:00:00.000


user-2
building-2
OUT
2024-04-10 09:00:00.000


user-2
building-3
OUT
2024-04-11 02:30:00.000


user-2
building-4
IN
2024-04-11 04:00:00.000


user-2
building-1
IN
2024-04-12 10:00:00.000


user-2
building-1
OUT
2024-04-12 11:00:00.000



I need to calculate swipe in and swipe out time. Sometimes we received partial record and we need to include those records also.
My expected output is:

Followed using windowing functions like lead, lag. After using those functions, I'm not able to continue further to get this output.
attached table data:
select 'user-1' as username,'building-1' as building,'IN' as action,'2024-04-10 01:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 
select 'user-1' as username,'building-1' as building,'OUT' as action,'2024-04-10 02:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 
select 'user-1' as username,'building-1' as building,'IN' as action,'2024-04-10 02:30:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all
select 'user-1' as username,'building-1' as building,'OUT' as action,'2024-04-10 04:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 
select 'user-1' as username,'building-1' as building,'IN' as action,'2024-04-11 10:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 
select 'user-1' as username,'building-1' as building,'OUT' as action,'2024-04-11 11:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 

select 'user-2' as username,'building-2' as building,'IN' as action,'2024-04-10 08:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 
select 'user-2' as username,'building-2' as building,'OUT' as action,'2024-04-10 09:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 
select 'user-2' as username,'building-3' as building,'OUT' as action,'2024-04-11 02:30:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all
select 'user-2' as username,'building-4' as building,'IN' as action,'2024-04-11 04:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 
select 'user-2' as username,'building-1' as building,'IN' as action,'2024-04-12 10:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp
union all 
select 'user-2' as username,'building-1' as building,'OUT' as action,'2024-04-12 11:00:00'::timestamp as timestamp

)

select * from _data


You can use lead/lag along with some CASE/WHEN/END for this.
Schema (PostgreSQL v15)
CREATE TABLE swipes (
    "username"  VARCHAR(6),
    "building"  VARCHAR(10),
    "action"    VARCHAR(3),
    "timestamp" TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO swipes
    ("username", "building", "action", "timestamp")
VALUES ('user-1', 'building-1', 'IN', '2024-04-10 01:00:00.000')
     , ('user-1', 'building-1', 'OUT', '2024-04-10 02:00:00.000')
     , ('user-1', 'building-1', 'IN', '2024-04-10 02:30:00.000')
     , ('user-1', 'building-1', 'OUT', '2024-04-10 04:00:00.000')
     , ('user-1', 'building-1', 'IN', '2024-04-11 10:00:00.000')
     , ('user-1', 'building-1', 'OUT', '2024-04-11 11:00:00.000')
     , ('user-2', 'building-2', 'IN', '2024-04-10 08:00:00.000')
     , ('user-2', 'building-2', 'OUT', '2024-04-10 09:00:00.000')
     , ('user-2', 'building-3', 'OUT', '2024-04-11 02:30:00.000')
     , ('user-2', 'building-4', 'IN', '2024-04-11 04:00:00.000')
     , ('user-2', 'building-1', 'IN', '2024-04-12 10:00:00.000')
     , ('user-2', 'building-1', 'OUT', '2024-04-12 11:00:00.000')
     -- added those rows to showcase the results when the same action happens twice in a row
     , ('user-3', 'building-1', 'IN', '2024-04-12 11:00:00.000')
     , ('user-3', 'building-1', 'IN', '2024-04-12 12:00:00.000')
     , ('user-3', 'building-1', 'OUT', '2024-04-12 13:00:00.000')
;


Query #1
-- Since the information may be partial we can't simply look at all "in"s or "out"s,
-- so we look at all the rows & end up with everything twice, hence the DISTINCT.
SELECT DISTINCT
       username
     , building
     , CASE
           WHEN action = 'IN' THEN timestamp
           -- To find the entry time corresponding to this "out" row, we'll look at the previous row.
           -- If it's an "in", then we keep the timestamp.
           -- If it's an "out", then there were 2 "outs" in a row, so the "in" value is set to null (see user-3's rows for an example of this).
           WHEN action = 'OUT' THEN
               CASE WHEN LAG(action) OVER user_actions_per_building_by_timestamp = 'IN'
                   THEN LAG(timestamp) OVER user_actions_per_building_by_timestamp
               END
       END AS "in"
     , CASE
           -- same concept as above, with IN/OUT & LAG/LEAD flipped.
           WHEN action = 'IN' THEN
               CASE WHEN LEAD(action) OVER user_actions_per_building_by_timestamp = 'OUT'
                   THEN LEAD(timestamp) OVER user_actions_per_building_by_timestamp
               END
           WHEN action = 'OUT' THEN timestamp
    END AS "out"
FROM swipes
WINDOW user_actions_per_building_by_timestamp AS (PARTITION BY username, building ORDER BY timestamp)
ORDER BY username, building, "in", "out";




username
building
in
out




user-1
building-1
2024-04-10T01:00:00.000Z
2024-04-10T02:00:00.000Z


user-1
building-1
2024-04-10T02:30:00.000Z
2024-04-10T04:00:00.000Z


user-1
building-1
2024-04-11T10:00:00.000Z
2024-04-11T11:00:00.000Z


user-2
building-1
2024-04-12T10:00:00.000Z
2024-04-12T11:00:00.000Z


user-2
building-2
2024-04-10T08:00:00.000Z
2024-04-10T09:00:00.000Z


user-2
building-3

2024-04-11T02:30:00.000Z


user-2
building-4
2024-04-11T04:00:00.000Z



user-3
building-1
2024-04-12T11:00:00.000Z



user-3
building-1
2024-04-12T12:00:00.000Z
2024-04-12T13:00:00.000Z




View on DB Fiddle

Another way could be to use a recursive CTE, which might be easier to understand if the conditions get more complex (and it would also perform differently, though you would need to check this against some actual data).

@Marth..Perfect thanks a lot.. i am trying this formula from last two days. Appreciated .
